# How do I pass an int map[60][60] array from my main.cpp file to my findpath.cpp file in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, argument-passing

Alright so I've got an array

```
int map[60][60];
```

which gets populated by walls  and with a start position and such in int main().

Later I call on my path finding algorithm which is located in another .cpp file

```
string route=findPath(xA, yA, xB, yB);
```

which passes random start and end points on the map to findPath. The problem I am having, is I really want to keep the map generation in a seperate file, and eventually move it out of main to its own .cpp. To make that possible, I need to be able to pass the finished map to findPath thus

```
findPath(xA, yA, xB, yB, map);
```

However I don't have a goddamned clue how to begin doing that, and my best efforts to find help online have resulted in failure. Although there are a lot of tutorials on how to do this, I haven't been able to either find one for my specific situation, or get it to work.

my best guess for my header file looks like this:

```
#ifndef FINDPATH_H
#define FINDPATH_H

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

string findPath(const int &, const int &, const int &, const int &, int [60][60]);
#endif
```

and my findPath Function declaration looks like this

```
    string findPath(const int & xCoordStart, const int & yCoordStart,
 const int & xCoordEnd, const int & yCoordEnd, int (&map)[60][60])
```

I'm having a really hard time figuring out how the hell to do this and implement it, please help.

Edit: Error I get with current code:

> Error 3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > __cdecl findPath(int const &,int const &,int
>   const &,int const &,int (* const)[60])"
>   (?findPath@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABH000QAY0DM@H@Z)
>   referenced in function _main  C:\Users\Cameron\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\Project2\Project2\main.obj  Project2

I'm fairly certain I'm doing something wrong in my header file, as the issue cropped up when I tried to used the int (&m)[60][60] format.

Prior to that it compiled, but failed at run time, by way of not actually passing the contents of the array. Instead the map was blank, resulting in the path finding algorithm drawing only straight lines.

Comment: What is the issue of your current attempt? What is the error message? At first glance, it looks ok to me, although the choice of reference integers is odd. Consider creating a class for your game map, so if you change it from a C-style array of exactly 60x60, you don't have to update tons of functions.

Comment: ""Error 3 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl findPath(int const &,int const &,int const &,int const &,int (* const)[60])" (?findPath@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABH000QAY0DM@H@Z) ""



I had it actually 'working' for a bit, but the actual content of the array wasn't being passed, it was just coming up blank, resulting in run-time failure (in this case, the path finding algorithm always choosing a straight line through walls).

Comment: Last parameter in header: `int [60][60]`, in implementation:`int (&) [60][60]`. Those two things are **not** equivalent. Therefore, the two functions have non-matching signatures and are thusly considered two *different* functions. The referred function in the header file decl and referred to  by your calling code has never actually been implemented, and you have instead implemented a function that is unused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three ways of passing an array from one function to another:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int (&m)[100][100])
{
   std::cout << m[10][10] << std::endl;
}

void bar(int (*m)[100])
{
   std::cout << m[10][10] << std::endl;
}

void baz(int (m)[][100])
{
   std::cout << m[10][10] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   int m [100][100];
   foo(m);
   bar(m);
   baz(m);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the posted header file, you are using `int [60][60])`. If you change it to `int (&)[60[60]`, it should work.

Comment: Yeeeeeep. That was it. I never found an example of how to do the header so I just guessed.